# About blank pages opening alone on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Since a few weeks, google chrome opens blank pages several times per minute, without any obvious reason. If I were using windows, I would think it comes from a virus, but that's way less likely with ubuntu.

So where do you think the problem comes from?

It also happens when I am not doing anything on the computer, including when chrome isn't open.

Thanks

Comment: Does it happen with other browsers? like Firefox.

Comment: Are you using gwibber or empathy?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am not using gwibber or empathy and it only happens with chrome.

Answer (score 5):

I think I've had the same issue and here's what solved it for me:
It appears that its because I had a Google account set in my *online accounts*, but Empathy was not able to connect, so I just deleted the Google account in the account list because I don't use it. Now no blank page opens.

*I saw this solution in [a topic on the French Ubuntu forums](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1286501).*

I have one way to reproduce it in my case: a blank page opens in Chrome each time I use the Unity launcher (for example, I press window, start typing `skype`, and press enter. Skype will launch and a blank page will be opened in Chrome). The problem is only with Chrome.

Comment: This is more like a work-around. But it does work.It would be nice however if someone found the solution to just stop the pop-ups. Its bad behavior. The correct function should be something smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. For some reason, Ubuntu was unable to access my Google account. After clicking "Grant Access" in the "Online Accounts" settings page, the problem appears to be solved.